# The SPUtility method MakeReadOnly() will show empty field instead of disabling a Person or Group field, when i am assigning it to a Group

Tags: 2013, development, list-form, aspx, sputility

I have a field named `Assigned To` inside my Create and Edit list forms. And i am using `SPUtility` library [link](https://sputility.codeplex.com/) to disable and enable certain fields. now the `Assigned To` field can be assigned to a Person or to a Group, as follow:-

[image]

And i am using this SPUtility method to make the `AssingedTo` field as read only inside the Create/Edit list forms if the item status = `closed` as follow:-

```
var internalStatusField = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('InternalStatus').GetValue();

if(internalStatusField === "Closed")
  {

    SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('AssignedTo').MakeReadOnly();    

  }
```

now the problem i am facing is that if the `AssignedTo` field is assigned to a group then when i make it as read only , i will get empty field as follow, instead of showing the group name:-

[image]

but if the AssignedTo field contain a user, then the username will be show correctly in a read-only field as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce why making a person or group read only using `SPUtility` will show empty field in-case the field is assigned to a group ??

Thanks

Hint. I am testing this using IE 11. now when i try to do the test using Firefox i will always get empty field even when i am assigning the field to a username..